# Default value of Dropdown changing when other HTML Element is selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a MVC form where depending upon a  value I want the dropdown's value to be set as default value. The code for my HTML select tag is as below.

```
<select name="xyz"id="xyz" v-model="data.xyz" class="form-control" @@change="CheckAllotment()" v-validate="'required'" ref="xyz">
    <option value="" disabled selected> Select Year </option>
    <option value="2020-2021"> 2020-2021 </option>
    <option value="2021-2022"> 2021-2022 </option>
    <option value="2022-2023"> 2022-2023 </option>
    <option value="2023-2024"> 2023-2024 </option>
    <option value="2024-2025"> 2024-2025 </option>
</select>
```

I am trying to change the value  via JS by selecting the element ID depending upon a particular value.

JS Code:

```
if (this.value == true) {               
    document.getElementById('xyz').selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Problem: The issue arises when i click on any other element in the form. the Dropdown value which was selected as default changes after the JS Function changes to the one which i selected initally.

I want that the data should remain as the default value which in my case should be selectedIndex = -1.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanking in advance

Comment: What is `financialYear` element. please post all the relevant code.

Comment: Apologies. Changed it.